# socketIO - override setInterval for movement on player entitity

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Im building an online multiplayer game where you can click on tiles to move to them. The tiles have an x and z position.

I dont know how to reset the clearInterval if a player clicks another tile in socket.io. Right now it doubles the speed because it duplicates the setInterval I guess and if I try to clearInterval at the beginning it seems not to target the old setInterval. I tried to bind the setInterval to the player[socket.id] object but got a Maximum call stack size exceeded error then.

How do I clear this specific setInterval for the player so it hasnt 2 setIntervals when I click a second tile while moving?

index.js (server)

```
players[socket.id] = {
    x: 0,
    z: 0,
    xTo:0,
    zTo:0,
    isMoving: false,
    playerId: socket.id,
    name: name,
    room: 'lobby'
};

//when client clicks on a tile
socket.on('moveRequest', function(pos) {
  //set clicked tile x/z to player entity 
  players[socket.id].xTo = pos[0];
  players[socket.id].zTo = pos[2];
  //only continiue if clicked tile is different from current tile
  if (players[socket.id].x !== players[socket.id].xTo) {
    //get direction left/right
    var xDiff = players[socket.id].xTo - players[socket.id].x;
    var xDirection = 'none';
    if (xDiff > 0) {
      console.log('player wants to move right');
      xDirection = 'right';
    } else {
      console.log('player wants to move left');
      xDirection = 'left';
    }
    //if there is wanted movement
    if (xDirection !== 'none') {
      //setInterval 60fps
      const moveInterval = setInterval(function() {
        //if direction is right and players current position is smaller then clicked position
        if (xDirection == 'right' && players[socket.id].x < players[socket.id].xTo) {
          //move player
          players[socket.id].x = players[socket.id].x + 0.03;
        } else {
          //if reached destination clear the interval
          xDirection = 'none';
          clearInterval(moveInterval);
        }
        //now send move to all players in room
        io.to('game').emit('playerMove', players[socket.id]);
      }, 1000 / 60);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Define `const moveInterval` globally, outside socket `moveRequest` handler function and try!

Comment: omg yeah that solved it totally. thanks a lot. shame I havent seen that.